# Query regarding boundary map in algebraic approach

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am studying The Schur multiplier by G. Karpilovsky, at page 5 (1.4) he defined a map called boundry map $d_{n+1}:C^{n}(G,A)\to C^{n+1}(G,A)$ by 
$$d_{n+1}f(x_1,x_2,\ldots x_{n+1})=f(x_2,\ldots x_{n+1})\times \Pi_{i=1}^nf(x_1,x_2,\ldots x_{i-1},x_ix_{i+1},\ldots x_{n+1})^{(-1)^i}f(x_1,x_2,\ldots x_n)^{(-1)^{n+1}}x_{n+1}$$

where $G$ is a group, $A$ is an abelian group and $C^n(G,A)$ is the set of functions from direct product of $n-$copies of $G$ to $A$.

> My question is that if $d_{n+1}$ is a boundary map then $d_n\circ d_{n+1}$ should be zero map, but I am not able to see this. Please help me regarding the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a proof by a direct computation with the coboundary operator, see my [lecture notes](https://homepage.univie.ac.at/Dietrich.Burde/papers/burde_16_coho_course.pdf) Lemma $2.2.2$ on page $23-24$.

Comment: Thanks for your notes sir..